# Batch file to remove .tmp files in a shared network location

Tags: excel, batch-file, ms-office

I have a problem affecting multiple user's where when they saved excel files to a shared drive it creates multiple.tmp files in the folder files which prevents user's from opening the spreadsheet.Effectively locking the sheet out.
When these are removed the spreadsheet opens fine.

How would I create a batch file to remove these files in the location Imports Share as of when they appear.

Im stuck on the part of deleting all files the appear with extension .tmp as they will be constant new ones appearing.

Comment: `del /f /q "\\network\blah\blah\name.tmp"`?

Comment: i'll recommend you to create a service application, and let it running for doing this job, instead of executing the bat file each time you want to clean that temp files.